# Sitecore indexing strategies (auto index rebuild not happening)

Tags: search, indexing, lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

I have configured the indexing with async strategy, but index is not rebuilding  after specified time interval.

Configuration for indexing:

```xml
<indexUpdateStrategies>
  <intervalAsyncWeb type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.IntervalAsynchronousStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <param desc="database">web</param>
    <param desc="interval">00:01:00</param>
    <CheckForThreshold>true</CheckForThreshold>
  </intervalAsyncWeb>
  <intervalAsyncMaster type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.IntervalAsynchronousStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <param desc="interval">00:01:00</param>
  </intervalAsyncMaster>
  <intervalAsyncCore type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.IntervalAsynchronousStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <param desc="interval">00:05:00</param>
  </intervalAsyncCore>
</indexUpdateStrategies>
```

Am i missing any configuration ?

Any relevant and useful links are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the configuration you have provided, you did not specify the Database for the **intervalAsyncMaster** and **intervalAsyncCore**

Thanks